# SMTPSenderRefused at /appointment

Tags: django-views, django-settings

I'm trying to send emails with Django, *sendmail*, but for some reason, it's throwing this error, and showing that the problem is my **email**, i.e this `['abrarshahriar360@gmail.com'],` line. It was working fine on development server, after I deployed it using heroku, everything is working fine, just when I'm trying to send an email, it's showing this. I have my *two factor authentication* turned **off** and less secure apps turned **on**. Still why is this error being SHown? Thanks in advance!

My views.py:

```
def appointment(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        your_name = request.POST['your-name']
        your_phone = request.POST['your-phone']
        your_email = request.POST['your-email']
        your_address = request.POST['your-address']
        your_schedule = request.POST['your-schedule']
        your_date = request.POST['your-date']
        your_message = request.POST['your-message']

        appointment = "Name: " + your_name + "  " + "Phone: " + your_phone + "  " + "Email: " + your_email + "  " + "Address: " + your_address + "  " + "Schedule: " + your_schedule + "  " + "Appointment Date: " + your_date + "  " + "Message: " + your_message 

        send_mail(
            'Appointment request form ' + your_name,
            appointment,
            your_email,
            ['abrarshahriar360@gmail.com'],
            )

        return render(request, 'appointment.html', {
            'your_name' : your_name,
            'your_phone' : your_phone,
            'your_email' : your_email,
            'your_address' : your_address,
            'your_schedule' : your_schedule,
            'your_date' : your_date,
            'your_message' : your_message
            })
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html', {})
```

My settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'

# Email Settings

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abrarshahriar360@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('Email_PASS')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True


django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually was my problem. I passed the wrong context variables. So it was throwing that error